# How to declare a tikz "directory" or group of keys

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

In the mwe below, I declare a key `/tikz/my key/radius`, and I set up `/tikz/my key` so that using `my key={radius=50pt}` works.

This is a common pattern, for example `decorate, decoration={lots of options here}`.

**Edit: I am looking for a `.is directory` flag, so that writing `/tikz/my key/.is directory` is equivalent to `/tikz/my key/.code={\pgfkeys{/tikz/my key/.cd,#1}}`.**

I tried setting up `/tikz/my key` with `/tikz/my key/.is family`, but this affects all following options on the node, e.g. it tries to reslove `debug my key` to `/tikz/my key/debug my key` instead of just `/tikz/debug my key`.

Is there a key handler similar to `.is family` that sets the key to accept a list of sub-keys, but doesn't apply `.cd` to the other options?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  %/tikz/my key/.is family,
  /tikz/my key/.code={
    \tikzset{%
      my key/.cd,%
      #1%
    }
  },
  /tikz/my key/radius/.initial=10pt,
  /tikz/my key/radius/.default=10pt,
}

\tikzset{
  debug my key/.style={
    my key/radius/.show value,
  }
}

\tikz\node[my key={radius=50pt}, debug my key] {};

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `.search also`? That's what I usually do so that unknown keys get rerouted to, say, `/tikz/` or whatever.

Comment: @cfr `.search also` would mean that in the later options, both keys in `/tikz/my key` and in `/tikz` would be available. This is not the case with `decoration`, for example: `\path[decoration={expanding waves}, expanding waves] …` gives as expected the error `I do not know the key '/tikz/expanding waves' for the second `expanding waves`. I'm trying to get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can use \pgfkeys inside the code (if I did understand your question correctly -- I'm not quite sure why you want/need the `.is family`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  /tikz/my key/.is family,
  /tikz/my key/.code={
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/my key/.cd,#1}
    }
  ,
  /tikz/my key/radius/.initial=10pt,
  /tikz/my key/radius/.default=10pt,
}

\tikzset{
  debug my key/.style={
    my key/radius/.show value,
  }
}

\tikz\node[my key={radius=50pt}, debug my key, line width=2pt,draw] {blblblb };

\end{document}
```

Btw: You can look in pgfmodulesdecoration.code.tex to find out that it done this way there too:

```
 /pgf/decoration/.code={\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/.cd,#1}},
```

Comment: I had looked in `tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex`, but not in `pgfmodulesdecoration.code.tex`. I'm looking for a `.is directory` flag, so that writing `/tikz/my key/.is directory` is equivalent to `/tikz/my key/.code={\pgfkeys{/tikz/my key/.cd,#1}}`. I edited my question to add this.

Comment: Well you could define a new handler. Something like `\pgfkeys{/handlers/.is directory/.code=
 {\pgfkeysedef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\noexpand\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.cd,##1}}}}
` could work. See pgfkeys.code.tex for examples.